# Drop-down box with Json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use jquery to populate the dropdown box with the following JSON data

```
    {
     "Name":["A","B","C"],
     "Movie":["X","Y","Z"]
    }
```

And this the script what I have done so far

```
   $("#firstbox").change(function(){
    var $selection=$(this);

   $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
    var i=$selection.val();
    var arr=[];

    switch(i){
        case 'Name':
            arr=data.Name.split(",");
            break;
        case 'Movie':
            arr=data.Movie.split(",");
            break;
    }       

    });

    });
```

My basic index.html is just like this

```
   <select id="firstbox">
            <option selected value="">---Select---</option> 
            <option value="Name">Name</option>
            <option value="Movie">Movie</option>
   </select>

   <select id="secondbox" name="">
            <option selected value="">---Generate---</option>
            <script src="myjs.js"> </script>
   </select>
```

The 'secondbox' drop-down should generate the value corresponding to the selections of 'firstbox' drop-down. The error I received is 'undefined split function'. Can anyone give me a hint ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`split` is a method of the `String` object, here you use it on the `Array` object.
You dont need to split as the Name and Movie keys are allready arrays in the JSON object.

```
$("#firstbox").on("change", function(e){
    var sel=$(this).val(); 
    $("#secondbox").empty();
    $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
        var values=data[sel] || ['Error : key not found'];
        $(values).each(function(index,element) {
             $("<option />", {value: element, text:element}).appendTo("#secondbox"); 
         });
    });
 });
```

Here is a working exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/cKBeE/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#firstbox").on("change", function(e){
 writeOptions();
}

function getJSONData(firstboxval) {
  //make ajax call to get data for second dropdown 
  //that corresponds to the value selected in firstbox 
  //then make function return the array of options
}

function writeOptions() {   
   var firstboxval = $("#firstbox").val();
   var optionValues = getJSONData(firstboxval);
   var dropDown = document.getElementById("secondbox");

   for(var i=0; i<optionValues.length; i++) {
       var key = i;
       var value = optionValues[i];
       dropDown.options[i] = new Option(value, key);
    }
}
```